# Creating nested JSON object for the following structure in Java using JSONObject?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to build a JSON Object similar to following the structure in java using JSONObject and JSONArray.

I have gone through various posts in stack overflow, which suggests using methods like push, put etc which I am unable to identify for JSONArray. Please help.

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "def": [
        {
            "setId": 1,
            "setDef": [
                {
                    "name": "ABC",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "XYZ",
                    "type": "STRING"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "setId": 2,
            "setDef": [
                {
                    "name": "abc",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "xyz",
                    "type": "STRING"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

With the imports `org.json.JSONArray` and `org.json.JSONObject`

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("name", "sample");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

JSONObject arrayElementOne = new JSONObject();
arrayElementOne.put("setId", 1);
JSONArray arrayElementOneArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject arrayElementOneArrayElementOne = new JSONObject();
arrayElementOneArrayElementOne.put("name", "ABC");
arrayElementOneArrayElementOne.put("type", "STRING");

JSONObject arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo = new JSONObject();
arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo.put("name", "XYZ");
arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo.put("type", "STRING");

arrayElementOneArray.put(arrayElementOneArrayElementOne);
arrayElementOneArray.put(arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo);

arrayElementOne.put("setDef", arrayElementOneArray);
array.put(arrayElementOne);
object.put("def", array);
```

I did not include first array's second element for clarity. Hope you got the point though.

EDIT:

The previous answer was assuming you were using `org.json.JSONObject` and `org.json.JSONArray`.

For `net.sf.json.JSONObject` and `net.sf.json.JSONArray` :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.element("name", "sample");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

JSONObject arrayElementOne = new JSONObject();
arrayElementOne.element("setId", 1);
JSONArray arrayElementOneArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject arrayElementOneArrayElementOne = new JSONObject();
arrayElementOneArrayElementOne.element("name", "ABC");
arrayElementOneArrayElementOne.element("type", "STRING");

JSONObject arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo = new JSONObject();
arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo.element("name", "XYZ");
arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo.element("type", "STRING");

arrayElementOneArray.add(arrayElementOneArrayElementOne);
arrayElementOneArray.add(arrayElementOneArrayElementTwo);

arrayElementOne.element("setDef", arrayElementOneArray);
object.element("def", array);
```

Basically it's the same, replacing the method 'put' for 'element' in JSONObject, and 'put' for 'add' in JSONArray.

Comment: thanks for your time, as I mentioned in my question I am unable to access put method of JSONArray. I am using net.sf.Json API to create this objects (JSONObject and JSONArray). Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I assumed you were using org.json.JSONObject and org.json.JSONArray. Sorry. According to http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html and http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html, i guess you could replace all 'put' methods for the 'element' method for JSONObject, and replace 'put' for 'add' in JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Here is one crude example.  You should be able to refine.  (You may be interested in this Java "tutorial" http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm#GLRBB

(This example uses the JSON reference implementation included in Java EE (and available here: https://java.net/projects/jsonp/downloads/directory/ri)

```
package com.demo;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator;

public class JSONExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Joseph White\\Downloads\\jsontext.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonGenerator gen = Json.createGenerator(writer);

    gen.writeStartObject().write("name", "sample")
        .writeStartArray("def")
          .writeStartObject().write("setId", 1)
             .writeStartArray("setDef")
                .writeStartObject().write("name", "ABC").write("type", "STRING")
                .writeEnd()
                .writeStartObject().write("name", "XYZ").write("type", "STRING")
                .writeEnd()
            .writeEnd()
          .writeEnd()
            .writeStartObject().write("setId", 2)
              .writeStartArray("setDef")
                .writeStartObject().write("name", "abc").write("type", "STRING")
                .writeEnd()
                .writeStartObject().write("name", "xyz").write("type", "STRING")
                .writeEnd()
              .writeEnd()
            .writeEnd()
          .writeEnd()
        .writeEnd();

    gen.close();

}

 }
```

Comment: This looks crazy and I bet it's a blast to debug.

Comment: This is an overkill.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/fmw122100/WLPRG/java-api-for-json-proc.htm#WLPRG1065

Comment: not looks enterprise standards code.