# Generating a JSON array

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I need to generate a JSON array object ("MainData") as shown below using Java. Can any one suggest to me how can be this done?

```
{
  "MainData":{
    "columnHeaderKeys":null,
    "rowHeaders":[
      {
        "id":0001,
        "name":abcd
      },
      {
        "id":0002,
        "name":xyz
      }
    ],
    "data":[
      {
        "id":0001,
        "rowId":"R1",
        "status":PASSED
      },
      {
        "id":0002,
        "rowId":"R2",
        "status":PASSED
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [google GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042638/creating-nested-json-object-for-the-following-structure-in-java-using-jsonobject

Answer (score 3):

Using [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), it's quite simple:

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.put("columnHeadersKeys", JSONObject.NULL);

JSONArray headers = new JSONArray();

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", 1);
obj.put("name", "abcd");
headers.put(obj);

obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", 2);
obj.put("name", "xyz");
headers.put(obj);

result.put("rowHeaders", headers);

JSONArray data = new JSONArray();

obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", 1);
obj.put("rowId", "R1");
obj.put("status", "PASSED");
data.put(obj);

obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", 2);
obj.put("rowId", "R2");
obj.put("status", "PASSED");
data.put(obj);

result.put("data", data);

String output = result.toString();
```

Note that the entire creation of the object can be chained in one statement - however I find it easier to read when it's split out.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library.

A sample code from [the tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String,Object> userData = new HashMap<String,Object>();
Map<String,String> nameStruct = new HashMap<String,String>();
nameStruct.put("first", "Joe");
nameStruct.put("last", "Sixpack");
userData.put("name", nameStruct);
userData.put("gender", "MALE");
userData.put("verified", Boolean.FALSE);
userData.put("userImage", "Rm9vYmFyIQ==");

mapper.writeValue(new File("user-modified.json"), userData);
```

Comment: whoops, forget the mapper! fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://json.org/java/). You will find many projects that will help you.

I would try [JSONObject.java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) from Crockford's [JSON for Java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) Github repository.

Simple usage :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject()
    .put("MainData", new JSONObject()
        .put("columnHeaderKeys", null)
        .put("rowHeaders", new JSONArray()
            .put(new JSONObject()
                .put("id", "001")
                .put("name", "abc")
            )
            .put(new JSONObject()
                .put("id", "002")
                .put("rowId", "R1")
            // ...
        )
    );
```

Output string with :

```
String jsonString = obj.toString();
```

or write directly to file :

```
obj.write(new FileWriter(new File("/path/to/destination/file")));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer I believe you already know this, however please look at "Provide context for links" paragraph. Otherwise it should rather be a helpful comment.

Comment: When I was writing that comment the answer looked like `Take a look here. You will find many projects that will help you.` Now it's merely better. C'mon, you are here long enough. Just look at @elias answer.

Comment: I could do the JSON creation successfully. Thank you all for your timely help and support.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this It works perfectly for me with this line 
`Log.i("MainJSON", MainJSON.toString());` I have printed Created `JSONObject`

```
try{
        JSONObject jo1=new JSONObject();
        jo1.put("id",001);
        jo1.put("name","abcd");

        JSONObject jo2=new JSONObject();
        jo2.put("id",002);
        jo2.put("name","xyz");

        JSONArray jarr1=new JSONArray();
        jarr1.put(0, jo1);
        jarr1.put(1, jo2);

        JSONObject jo3=new JSONObject();
        jo3.put("id",0001);
        jo3.put("rowId","R1");
        jo3.put("status","PASSED");

        JSONObject jo4=new JSONObject();
        jo4.put("id",0002);
        jo4.put("rowId","R2");
        jo4.put("status","PASSED");

        JSONArray jarr2=new JSONArray();
        jarr2.put(0, jo3);
        jarr2.put(1, jo4);

        JSONObject MainDataObj=new JSONObject();
        MainDataObj.put("rowHeaders", jarr1);
        MainDataObj.put("data", jarr2);
        MainDataObj.put("columnHeaderKeys", "null");

        JSONObject MainJSON=new JSONObject();
        MainJSON.put("MainData", MainDataObj);

        Log.i("MainJSON", MainJSON.toString());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```