# I want to build a JSON Object similar to following the structure in java using JSONObject and JSONArray. How can I do it?

Tags: java, arrays, web-services, json

This is the json.
Something similar to [Creating nested JSON object for the following structure in Java using JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042638/creating-nested-json-object-for-the-following-structure-in-java-using-jsonobject) will help.

```
{
      "taskAssings": [
        {
          "taskAssigned": {
            "id": "3c814009-82f7-4246-bc51-2d263e758561"
          },
          "taskAssignee": {
            "id": "3c814009-82f7-4246-bc51-2d263e758561"
          }
        }
      ],
      "description": "TestTaskDescription",
      "assignTo": {
        "id": "3c814009-82f7-4246-bc51-2d263e758561"
      },
      "name": "taskname",
      "status": {
        "id": "7d8a0d80-5c93-46cc-982d-47399503beaa"
      },
      "priority": {
        "id": "842a9a9c-4a1a-4f70-bf4d-8181b482f651"
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to be a bit specific and clear about your query... Have you googled? Do you understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: PLEASE POST YOUR CODE OR OTHERS WILL EAT YOU!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `JSONSimple library` and form the object in this way-

You have to import `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and `org.json.simple.JSONObject` for using this code.

```
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();

    JSONObject holder=new JSONObject();
    JSONArray taskAssings = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject taskAssigned=new JSONObject();
    taskAssigned.put("id", "3c814009-82f7-4246-bc51-2d263e758561");

    JSONObject taskAssignee=new JSONObject();
    taskAssignee.put("id", "3c814009-82f7-4246-bc51-2d263e758561");

    holder.put("taskAssigned",taskAssigned);
    holder.put("taskAssignee",taskAssignee);
    taskAssings.add(holder);

    object.put("taskAssings", taskAssings);

    JSONObject status=new JSONObject();
    status.put("id", "7d8a0d80-5c93-46cc-982d-47399503beaa");
    object.put("status", status);

    JSONObject assignTo=new JSONObject();
    assignTo.put("id", "3c814009-82f7-4246-bc51-2d263e758561");
    object.put("assignTo", assignTo);


    JSONObject priority=new JSONObject();
    priority.put("id", "842a9a9c-4a1a-4f70-bf4d-8181b482f651");
    object.put("priority",priority);

    object.put("description", "TestTaskDescription");
    object.put("name", "taskname");
```