# java : create nested json object from String

Tags: java, json

I want to create `org.json.JSONObject` from String.
the String is `"user.phone.num : 00113"`. the result that i would like to have is `org.json.JSONObject` object with this format:

```
{
user: 
     { 
       phone:  {num: 00113}
     }
}
```

so is there any built in method to achieve this result. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need `org.json.JSONObject` or maybe just simple `String` but in `JSON` format?

Comment: You may check this link -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042638/creating-nested-json-object-for-the-following-structure-in-java-using-jsonobject

Comment: I need `org.json.JSONObject`.

Comment: how would be your string if you have json like this {attr1:{attr2:'ebrahim'},att3:'ps'}?

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi in this case i will have two String the first is `attr1.attr2: ebrahim` and the second is `att3: ps` . I build these json object , then i build the global json object

Comment: i know this.i want to know between this two section what delemiter you put.,some thing like this? attr1.attr2: ebrahim,att3: ps or what ? or your line are splitted by newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if every line of your json is splitted yo can try this code

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by ebi on 7/3/17.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        String str = "user.phone.num : 00113";
        String json_str = str_to_json(str);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_str);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }

    public static String str_to_json(String jsonByDot){
        int valOffset = jsonByDot.indexOf(":");
        String keys = jsonByDot.substring(0,valOffset).trim();
        String val = jsonByDot.substring(valOffset+1).trim();

        String keysArr[] = keys.split("\\.");
        String output = "";
        for(String key:keysArr){
            output+="{"+key+":";
        }
        output+=val;
        for (int i = 0 ;i<keysArr.length;i++){
            output+="}";
        }

        return  output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below -

```
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        obj1.put("birthdate", "01-01-2017");
        obj1.put("age", new Integer(18));

   JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("name", "abc");
        obj2.put("details", obj1);
```