# How can I add items to a JSON Object properly?

Tags: java, json

1) Below attaching the updated code have changed the names of files according to my need:Most of the errors lie in the TestObjectToJson method. Output : want To return the json object

'''
}'''

2) Another method to call this json output and only return the received id 
output : 134

Comment: What error? What package is `JSONObject` from?

Comment: Are you asking how to create `legs`? Just `put` another `JSONObject`.

Comment: public class TestObjectToJson {
        private Long tradeid = 145L;
        private Long trade_Group_id = 324L;
        private String target ="LEX";
        private void main(String[] args) {
            TestObjectToJson j = new TestObjectToJson();
            obj.put("target_group_id", "324L");
            obj.put("target ", "LEX");
            obj.put("trade_id", "145L");
            obj.put("status", "ELIGIBLE");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(obj);
            System.out.println(json); }

Comment: Why are you using GSON as well as JSONObject? Choose one library. Also, don't post code in comments. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't see an error in any of that. It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: org.json is one JSON library (providing `JSONObject`) and Gson is another one. You don't need two of them. Choose one and stick to it.

Comment: The same way you inserted everything else with `put`. Create a new `JSONObject` and `put` it into the first one.

Comment: Right, put those 2 other attributes in the new `JSONObject`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating nested JSON object for the following structure in Java using JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042638/creating-nested-json-object-for-the-following-structure-in-java-using-jsonobject)

Comment: If you want 134 to be a number, don't put quotes around it. Do you want the string "134L", or the number 134?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**ultimate update**

```
// Root.java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.util.List;

@JsonPropertyOrder({"received_id", "target", "legs"})
public class Root {
    private long receivedId;
    private String target;
    private List<Leg> legs;

    public long getReceivedId() { return receivedId; }
    public void setReceivedId(long id) { this.receivedId = id; }

    public String getTarget() { return target; }
    public void setTarget(String t) { this.target = t; }

    public List<Leg> getLegs() { return legs; }
    public void setLegs(List<Leg> legs) { this.legs = legs; }
}
```

---

```
// Leg.java

public class Leg {
    private long receivedGroupId;
    private String status;

    public long getReceivedGroupId() { return receivedGroupId; }
    public void setReceivedGroupId(long id) { this.receivedGroupId = id; }

    public String getStatus() { return status; }
    public void setStatus(String st) { this.status = st; }
}
```

---

```
// Test.java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setReceivedId(134L);
        root.setTarget("none");
        Leg leg = new Leg();
        leg.setReceivedGroupId(234L);
        leg.setStatus("active");
        root.setLegs(Arrays.asList(leg));
        String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

---

```
// output
{
  "received_id" : 134,
  "target" : "none",
  "legs" : [ {
    "received_group_id" : 234,
    "status" : "active"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: private Legs legs it should be private List<Leg> legs right ? Also do you think making the class leg static within the root class is a good decision ?

Comment: _it should be private List<Leg> legs right ?_  Yes.  _Also do you think making the class leg static within the root class is a good decision?_  Which class `leg`?  We have class `Leg`,  Yes, it is acceptable.to have static class for brevity.

Comment: Yes was talking about class Leg. Thanks can you please update your answer as well!

Comment: What for?  Does it make any difference?

Comment: private List<Legs> legs;

    public List<Legs> getLegs() { return legs; }

    public void setLegs(List<Legs> legs) { this.legs = legs; }     I have added this but the "root.setLegs(List<legs>);" throws error is this the right format ?

Comment: I updated the response with working example, though I don't believe that it might help you.