# How to create a nested JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Below is my code. I still need to add the "studentInfo" field.

```java
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("name", "ALEX JAMES");
jo.put("id", "22284666");
jo.put("age","13")
```

JSON body message to be created:

```js
{
    "body": {
        "studentInfo": {
            "name": "ALEX JAMES",
            "id": "22284666",
            "age": "13"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating nested JSON object for the following structure in Java using JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042638/creating-nested-json-object-for-the-following-structure-in-java-using-jsonobject) Specifically, each nested element is its own JSONObject or JSONArray.

Comment: Note that in any real-world Java application you would use Jackson or Gson.

Comment: Please note I don't have an Array[] in my example only field grouping under "studentInfo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can nest objects

```
JSONObject studentInfo = new JSONObject();
studentInfo.put("name", "ALEX JAMES");
studentInfo.put("id", "22284666");
studentInfo.put("age","13");

JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
body.put("studentInfo" , studentInfo);

JSONObject wrapper = new JSONObject();
wrapper.put("body" , body);
```

Answer (score 2):

This standalone example seems to do what you want:

```java
import org.json.JSONObject;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("body", body);

    JSONObject si = new JSONObject();
    body.put("studentInfo", si);
    si.put("name", "Alex James");
    si.put("id", "22284666");
    si.put("age", 13);

    System.out.println(jo.toString(4));
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{"body": {"studentInfo": {
    "name": "Alex James",
    "id": "22284666",
    "age": 13
}}}
```

Test it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@ColonelCoder/ImpureTruthfulMethods).